# How to do a TextJoin and combine few strings in one field in SQL BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like the below:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | $10 |
| Cell 2 | $20 |
| Cell 3 | $30 |

How to write in SQL (BigQuery) a code to have a result like the below? text joining Column A results using delimiter ";", and summing all values in Column B?

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1; Cell 2; Cell 3 | $60 |

Thanks in advance!

couldn't work it out by myself :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select string_agg(ColumnA, '; ') ColumnA, sum(ColumnB) ColumnB` as in below example

```
with your_table as (
  select 'Cell 1' ColumnA, 10 ColumnB union all
  select 'Cell 2', 20 union all
  select 'Cell 3', 30 
)
select string_agg(ColumnA, '; ') ColumnA, sum(ColumnB) ColumnB
from your_table
```

with output

[image]